# GCP serverless network endpoint group don't show Cloud Run services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

I have couple of services on Cloud Run, and I'm trying to create a load balancer to sit in front of them and route the traffic to them based on some path rules.

But, when I create the backend service (and I choose `Serverless network endpoint group` in `Backend type`, and I go to create a "Serverless network endpoint group", I choose the region that my Cloud Run services are located in and I don't see them in the `service` dropdown menu.

The Cloud Run services:
[image]

The Serverless network endpoint group creation page:
[image]

I tried every region, and read the GCP docs, and can't figure out why it's happening.

Edit: Before I choose the region, I do see all of my cloud run services, but when I do choose a region the list gets empty:
[image]

Comment: Did you check this link? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless

Comment: @razimbres yes. I follow this tutorial when trying to create the load balancer.

Comment: I reported the bug to Google yesterday. It's known by Google (Internal number 231158500). You can use the GCLOUD command to create your serverless NEG and bypass the UI bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `gcloud` cli tool in order to create the serverless NEG

```
gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups create <neg-name> \
  --region=<region> \
  --network-endpoint-type=serverless \
  --cloud-run-service=<serviceName>
```